# Wordpress via docker on ec2 aws , try to connect to my sql RDS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I tried to connect my wordpress that have elb+ssl with amazon , to rds on aws.

but i cant see all the information , color templates that in the webs only black and white

i think that somting with mysql.

thanks for helping.

[image]

Comment: "i think that somting with mysql" why do you think that? There is nothing to indicate a database connection error here. It's rendering post content, so it's connected to the database. It isn't rendering CSS properly. You need to view your browser's developer console and network tabs to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When connecting to an RDS instance from an application running on EC2, check your Inbound Rules. Also make sure your RDS instance accepts Public connections. For more information, please check [Controlling access with security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html).

Comment: its was missing rule , thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It seems RDS connection works, the issue might be the loading of CSS and JS.
The Developer tools (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/) on the Console tab you might get some hint.

I suspect Cross origin resource sharing issue. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)